# Javascript regex- How to find PascalCase items inside of group

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-group

I'm needing to convert something like this:

`[[Click here|ThisIsALink]]`

to:

`[Click here](https://example.com/this-is-a-link)`

I'm able to find the first `[[Click here|ThisIsALink]]` by using this regex `/\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]/g` which I can replace to turn it into `[Click here](https://example.com/ThisIsALink])`, but how then can I take that last part and convert it to `this-is-a-link`? I've tried a few things but I seem to be finding all PascalCased occurrences and not just the occurrences that happen within the first found regex pattern. (I am converting .md files to .pdf, so it is a full page of content, not just these links).

Here's what I have so far

```
var exampleUrl = "https://example.com/";
var urlOne = /\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]/g;

data.replace(urlOne, "[$1](" + exampleUrl + "$2)"));
```

This results in:
`[Click here](https://example.com/ThisIsALink)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const texts = ["Text [[Click here|ThisIsALink]] text...",
               "Text [[Click here|This-Is-A-Link]] text..."];
const exampleUrl = "https://example.com/";
const urlOne = /\[\[((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)\|(.*?)]]/g;
for (var text of texts) {
  console.log(
    text.replace(urlOne, (_,x,y) =>
                 `[${x}](${exampleUrl}${y.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '')
                                         .replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, '-$&')
                                         .toLowerCase()})`) );
}
```

*Regex #1 details*:

- `\[\[` - `[[` string
- `((?:(?!\[\[).)*?)` - Group 1: any char other than line break chars, zero or more times, as few as possible, that does not start `[[` char sequence
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `]]` - a `]]` string.

The *second regex*, `(?!^)[A-Z]`, is applied to the Group 2 contents, and matches any uppercase ASCII letter that is not at the start of the string. The `-$&` replacement just appends `-` before the match.

The extra regex, `.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '')`, will remove all non-alpha chars from the Group 2 contents before inserting hyphens.

Comment: Ah thank you that worked perfect! I got one minor thing wrong in my question, I switched the brackets and the parenthesis around on accident. End format should be `[Click here](https://example.com/this-is-a-link)`. I updated your answer to just 

`.replace(urlOne, (_, x, y) => `[${x}](${exampleUrl}${y.replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, '-$&').toLowerCase()})`)`

Comment: Actually, I'm running into one problem. If I have a link like this
`[[Click Here|This-Is-A-Link]]` it is now converting it to `[[Click Here|this--is--a--link]]` which is unwanted.

Comment: @Designxsteph Remove all non-alpha chars, `${y.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '').replace(/(?!^)[A-Z]/g, '-$&')`

Answer (score 0):

This approach does find and replace the by the OP mentioned pattern in a text of any given length regardless of how often the pattern is matched within this text.

It also uses a very straightforward regex for [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

The regex does look like that ... [`/\[\[([^|]+)\|([^\]]+)\]\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/qBQ7Nb/1) ... and reads like this ...

1. `\[\[` ... match (literally) two open square brackets ...
2. `([^|]+)` ... capture every character sequence ***(the link text)*** that is not a pipe  ...
3. `\|` ... then match a pipe ...
4. `([^\]]+)` ... capture every character sequence ***(the very url)***  that is not a closing square bracket ...
5. `\]\]` ... then match two closing square brackets.
6. `/ ... /g` ... flag regex as globally to be processed/applied pattern.

```js
const sampleUrl = 'https://example.com/'
const sampleText = `Text [[Link A|ThisIsLinkA]] text. Text [[Link B|thisIsLinkB]] text.
Text [[Link C|This-Is-Link-C]] text.
Text [[Link D|ThisIsLinkD]] text. Text [[Link E|-this--Is--Link--E]] text.`;

function convertLinkMarkup(text, baseUrl) {
  function ensureKebabCase(str) {
    return str
      .replace((/([A-Z])/g), '-$1') // - prefix any latin uppercase char with '-'.
      .replace((/-+/g), '-')        // - replace any '-' sequence with a single '-'.
      .replace((/^-+/g), '')        // - trim any leading '-' sequence.
      .toLowerCase();               // - lower-case the result.
  }
  function createLinkMarkup(match, text, path) {
    return `[${ text }](${ baseUrl }${ ensureKebabCase(path) })`;
  }
  const regXUrl = (/\[\[([^|]+)\|([^\]]+)\]\]/g);

  return text.replace(regXUrl, createLinkMarkup);
}

console.log(
  sampleText,
  '\n\n... => ...\n\n',
  convertLinkMarkup(sampleText, sampleUrl)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```